# Why does my HTML form not send user input to Google Sheets properly when I have an onsubmit event in my form?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently making an expense tracker. The HTML form with user input sends data to a Google Sheet and simultaneously executes the following `addExpense()` function;

```js
function addExpense()
{



        clothingID={'id':Date.now(),'clothingType':clothingType.value, 'brand': brand.value, 'amnt':amnt.value, };
        clothingArray.push(clothingID);
        count1++;
        showTotalBalance();
        showDifference();
        expenseHistory();
        clothingType.value='';
        amnt.value='';
        brand.value = '';
        setItemInStorage();

    
   
}
```

The HTML form looks like this without the `onsubmit` event:

```html
     <form method = "POST" action = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwo9AKU8OB5YXs_l0w3wqKoZDYp6F5C3EuarHeQVILt4CK9zaIhmGQETz7StlOc2P/exec' >
              <div class="row">
                 <div  class="six columns">
                    <label>Clothing type</label>
        <input  name = "Type" id = 'type' style = "width: 50%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the clothing type" id="exampleEmailInput">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Amount</label>
           <input name = "Amount" id="amnt" style = "width: 24%;" type="number" placeholder="Enter number" id="exampleEmailInput">
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <label style = 'padding-bottom: 1pt;' for="exampleEmailInput">Clothing brand</label>
                            <input name = "Store" id="brand" style = "width: 24%;" type="text" placeholder="Enter the clothing brand" id="exampleEmailInput">
                          </div>
                    
         <button type = 'submit' class="button-primary">Add expense</button>
                              
</form>
```

When I submit this form, the data is placed into a Google Sheet without problems, as such:

[image: Google Sheet Correct Ouput]

However, I would like the form to both execute the `addExpense()` function, and to also send the data to Google Sheets. Here is what happens when the `addExpense()` function is executed upon form submission:

[image: addExpense()]

This is only achievable when the form element looks like this:

```js
 <form  onsubmit='addExpense()'>
```

When I place both the `action` attribute and the `onsubmit` event to my form as such:

```js
<form method="POST"  action ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwo9A2AKU8OB5YXs_l0w3wqKoZDYp6F5C3EuarHeQVILt4CK9zaIhmGQETz7StlOc2P/exec" onsubmit='addExpense()'>
```

I only get the date (generated by the `Date()` object) returned in my Google Sheet, but the `addExpense()` function works fine:

[image: Date object only]

Any ideas on why this is occuring, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Probably because of `clothingType.value=''; amnt.value=''; brand.value = '';`  Those will clear out your input elements before the submit happens.

Comment: @James but then why is it working fine if I do not have `onsubmit='addExpense()` in `<form>`?

Comment: Because the code that clears out the input elements is *within* addExpense, so by removing the onsubmit you're not running it.

Comment: @James apologies, you were correct. I replaced `amnt.value='';` with `amnt.value='d';` and my Google Sheet did indeed update. Would you know how to fix this error?

Comment: @James im assuming that removing `clothingType.value=''; amnt.value=''; brand.value = '';` would fix the issue, correct?

Comment: I would expect that once the form is submitted, your inputs get cleared out automatically and you could just remove those 3 lines of code entirely.

Comment: @James yes thank you very much. feel free to post your solution as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
clothingType.value='';
amnt.value='';
brand.value = '';
```

clothingType, amnt, and brand are live references to the input elements in question.  Setting the value to empty string will have the effect that when you submit the form, those entries will be blank (because you set them to blank!).

I think the reason you are doing this is to clear out the form once it's submitted.  However I don't think you need to, usually once you submit and reload a form it will be cleared out automatically.